# ImageButton + dialog issue

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

Hey I am trying to make a dialog. But the whole dialog is not showing and only the bottom 3 imagebuttons are showing: What is wrong here? And when I click the buttons inside the dialog nothing happens even though I made a switch case.

customtype_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AutoMode"
    android:background="@color/black" >    

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/dialog_relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"    
    android:layout_above="@+id/dialog_relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_btn1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/track_run"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/dialog_relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dialog_relativeLayout1"
        />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/dialog_btn2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/track_bike"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dialog_relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dialog_btn1"
        />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/dialog_btn3"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dialog_btn2"
        android:background="@drawable/track_walk"
        />
 </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/dialog_relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/dialog_btn4"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/track_ski"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/dialog_relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dialog_relativeLayout2"
        />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/dialog_btn5"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/track_boat"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dialog_relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dialog_btn4"
        />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/dialog_btn6"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/track_snow_boarding"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dialog_relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dialog_btn5"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>




routeType = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.saveRoute_activityType);
        routeType.setOnClickListener(typeListener);
```

SaveRouteActivity.java

This is my listener.

```
View.OnClickListener typeListener = new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    switch(v.getId()){
                    case R.id.saveRoute_activityType:
                        Dialog typedialog = new Dialog(SaveRouteActivity.this);
                        typedialog.setContentView(R.layout.customtype_dialog);
                        typedialog.setTitle("Select type");
                        typedialog.setCancelable(true);
                        typedialog.show();
                        break;

                    case R.id.dialog_btn1:
                        txtType.setText("Run");
                        routeType.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.track_run);
                        break;

                    case R.id.dialog_btn2:
                        txtType.setText("Bike");
                        routeType.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.track_bike);
                        break;

                    case R.id.dialog_btn3:
                        txtType.setText("Walk");
                        routeType.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.track_walk);
                        break;

                    case R.id.dialog_btn4:
                        txtType.setText("Ski");
                        routeType.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.track_ski);
                        break;

                    case R.id.dialog_btn5:
                        txtType.setText("Boat");
                        routeType.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.track_boat);
                        break;

                    case R.id.dialog_btn6:
                        txtType.setText("Snowboarding");
                        routeType.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.track_snow_boarding);
                        break;
                    }

                }
            };
```

Comment: How do you display the dialog? Also, do you call `setOnClickListener()`? You might want to consider using a different `OnClickListener` for each button. This will remove the need for a switch statement.

Comment: I make a new Dialog as you can see in the first case...

Comment: My guess is that `setContentView()` is ignored because the Dialog has not been inflated yet. Typically you should call this method in an `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `typedialog.setContentView(R.layout.customtype_dialog);` is ignored because the Dialog has not been inflated yet. To fix the problem, you should create a subclass of `Dialog` and call `setContentView()` in its `onCreate()` method.

Comment: I can post the whole java class if you want to see it?

Comment: @IlhamiDogan Nope. If anything, you might want to start a new Android project from scratch which recreates the issue. This will allow you to focus your code more. If you do this, I will be glad to look at the code for your simplified example.

Comment: @IlhamiDogan If you don't understand my answer, please follow my previous suggestion to create a new Android project to illustrate the issue with the dialog showing. Make the new project as simple as possible so that it only contains the code necessary to recreate your problem. I will be glad to look at this example when you have done so.